# Syntax Error SQL UPDATE in MS Access with JOIN on same table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm getting a syntax error within MS Access VBA whereas the same line perfectly works fine in SQL Server:

```sql
UPDATE a 
SET a.Result = b.Result, a.Part = b.Part 
FROM tbl_Parts a 
JOIN ( SELECT b.* FROM tbl_Parts b WHERE b.ID = 180) b 
ON b.Part_Nr = a.Part_Nr;
```

I'm trying to use one row as a template and copy it's content to already existing other rows from the same Part-ID.

Comment: Access and SQL Server don't use the same dialect of SQL.

Comment: In Msacess the `SET` comes after the `JOIN`. The syntax is `UPDATE TBL1 INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.X = TBL2.Y SET TBL1.P = TBL2.Q`

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: Is there any documentation about the differences?

Comment: Not that I know of - for my own purposes I have a list of standard syntax for UPDATE/DELETE on joins for the DBs that I most familiar with, but I don't know of any site that gives a complete comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
UPDATE tbl_Parts AS a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_Parts WHERE ID = 180) AS b
ON b.Part_Nr = a.Part_Nr
SET a.Result = b.Result, a.Part = b.Part;
```